# Is it possible to use FieldSets as Visualforce Component attribute?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, fieldsets

I get a strange error message stating:

> Compilation error: Wrong type for attribute <c:sobjecttable
>   displayed="{!$ObjectType.UP2GO_2F__PriceSchedule__c.FieldSets.DisplayedOnDliEdit}">.
>   Expected FieldSet, found FieldSetMember

when i try to use this custom VF component

```
<apex:component controller="TableCtrl" selfClosing="true" layout="block">
        <apex:attribute name="displayed" type="Schema.FieldSet" assignTo="{!displayedFields}" required="true" description="" /> 

        <apex:pageBlockSection>
         ....
```

in a VF page like that

```
    <c:sobjectTable records="priceSchedules" 
                    displayed="{!$ObjectType.Part__c.FieldSets.MyFields}" />              
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

I know for sure that MyFields is a `FieldSet`. You cannot even reference `FieldSetMembers` in VF pages. So this error message does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! At least in parts....

Expression of this type

```
{!$ObjectType.Object__c.FieldSets.SetName}
```

in Visualforce evaluate to `Schema.FielSetMember[]` and not `FieldSet`. So when i changed my component attribute to

```
<apex:attribute name="displayed" type="Schema.FieldSetMember[]" assignTo="{!displayedFields} ../>
```

everything the page compiles.

But it never loads, as Salesforce seems to be unable to pass the array to the assigned controller variable. The page only render the error**

> Cannot convert the value of '{!displayedFields}' to the expected type.

**So I would answer my own question with: No, it is not possible to pass FieldSet information into Visualforce components.**